# Detecting Registry Key with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, registry

Using VS2013 and VB.NET (Framework 4.5), and no matter what I do, I can't detect if a key value exists.  I'm trying to detect if a value exists, if it does exist update with a value from a combobox or add it if it doesn't exit.

Key is `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Device`.

The code I've been tinkering with is below. Any thoughts?

```
Dim l_subKeyPath As String = "HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Device"
Dim l_regKey = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(l_subKeyPath)

If l_regKey Is Nothing Then
   ' if nothing then key doesn't exists
  Else
   ' key exists
End If
```

The code always returns 'Is Nothing' even when the key exists.

Comment: Do you have rights to that, credentials to access that part of the registry. I had exactly the same issue and it was because of permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this.

```
Dim l_subKeyPath As String = "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows"
Dim l_regKey = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(l_subKeyPath)

If l_regKey Is Not Nothing Then
   Dim deviceValue as String =   l_regKey.GetValue("Device")
  // 
Else
End If
```

Your code has problem as you have provided complete path of registry key with its value.
Also your code contain HKEY_USers\S-1-5-18 which is not required if you use Registry.CurrentUser

Comment: I had added the HKEY_Users in a vain attempt.  Your approach worked.  Thanks.